# I want to select using two tables where one table Data becomes second table column

Tags: sql

```
I have 2 tables . Like -
Table_A :
id   Locale_id   Text
 1    EN          TESTEN  
 2    ZH          TESTZH
 3    ES          TESTES
 4    EN          TESTEN_2
 5    ES          TESTES_2
 6    ZH          TESTZH_2
 7    CA          TESTEN 

Table_B :
id     EN           ES            ZH           CA
 1    TESTEN      TESTES        TESTZH       TESTEN
 2    TESTEN_2    TESTES_2      TESTZH_2
```

Now, I want to select the id from Table_A and Table_B on the basis of text similarities. Is this possible? Even I want to avoid 'CA' to come again in Select Query
Means the result would be like:

Select Table_A.id as OLD_ID, Table_B.id as NEW_ID(This is how These two column comes from), Whereas id in Table_B don't have any relation to Table_A id column.

```
OLD_ID  NEW_ID  TEXT
1       1       TESTEN
2       1       TESTZH
3       1       TESTES
4       2       TESTEN_2
5       2       TESTES_2
6       2       TESTZH_2
```

Comment: Where do you get old_id and new_id from? I don't see the logic.

Comment: I am updating the question..

Comment: That is still confusing. A.id 2 is TESTZH, but in your results show old_id 2 to be TESTES. B has no id 3, but there is a new_id 3 in your results.

Comment: Yes You are right. It was by mistake only. I think you understand it now. B dont' need id 3 as the select already covers all the TEXT.

Comment: Getting closer. Is new_id 3 a typo for new_id 2?

Comment: yes its a Typo .....

Answer (score 1):

Table_A has a much better design than Table_B. You can select a given language easily (and can add a language easily). To get the strings per language from Table_B you need several queries that you'd glue together with UNION ALL here.

```
select a.id as old_id, b.id as new_id, a.text
from table_a a
join
(
  select id, 'EN' as locale_id, en as text from table_b
  union all
  select id, 'ES' as locale_id, es as text from table_b
  union all
  select id, 'ZH' as locale_id, zh as text from table_b
) b on b.locale_id = a.locale_id and b.text = a.text;
```

Comment: Great > Though it is giving me error on 2nd line. It says:Invalid object name 'A'. I have prefix table name to it and it works.

Comment: In your original request the table's name was A. Now it's Table_A, so of course A must be changed to Table_A in my answer. I'm correcting it.

Comment: Just a remark as to table design: I said Table_A has a much better design, but it lacks the information which records belong together. You would usually have one table for the word with columns word_id and a text, e.g. 1/'long (verb)', 2/'long (adjective)'. Then you'd have a second table for internationalization with columns word_id, locale_id and text, e.g. 1/'EN'/'long', 1/'ES'/'anhelar', 2/'EN'/'long', 2/'ES'/'largo'.

Comment: Well said. This is the legacy data table developed prior. I don't have any control to modify it. Thanks for the nice suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
The below query will you the result that you want:

SELECT A.id AS OLD_ID
        ,B.id AS NEW_ID
        ,B.[TEXT] 
FROM [Table A] AS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT Temp.id, 
        Temp.LOCALE_ID,
        Temp.[TEXT] 
        FROM [Table B]
        UNPIVOT ([TEXT] FOR LOCALE_ID IN (EN,ES,ZH,CA)) Temp) AS B 
ON A.[TEXT] = b.[TEXT]

If you want to exclude Locale_id of CA from the result set, please add the below where clause at end of the query.

WHERE B.locale_id NOT IN ('CA')
```

Comment: UNPIVOT is what i was hoping for, but the problem is that 'CA' is not the only case there can be multiple Locales. So can I distinguish using text only. Whereas B table don't have Text column.

Comment: okay. So.. If a Text(TESTEN) appears again in a row you have to skip it? in your example CA??